# In Win32 Serial Port Programming(C++) How to findout whether other end is alive or not?

Tags: winapi, serial-port

I am developing an application to communicate with hardware module and control it. Programatically I have to find out weather other Hardware end is alive or not. In Win32 is there any features to find out this at serial port initialization time? (when calling `CreateFile(...)`)

[We can send something and wait for reply. But I feel that it is bit odd approach.]

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the device.

If your device indicates readiness using the flow control bits (i.e. DSR or CTS), then [`GetCommModemStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363258.aspx).

For an arbitrary serial device, you would need a transceiver capable of distinguishing zero voltage from a valid mark or space signal, and standard PC serial ports aren't.